# add parameter to an http header using java webservice

Tags: java, rest, http, header

i have this http header :

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 17:08:29 GMT
```

And what i want is to add 2 parameter: mytotalcount and mytotalresult.

i have to add this into my response however it's not working i can't do:

```
    response.Headers.Add("mytotalcount", "10");
```

Also can't do

```
    request.setAttribute("mytotalcount","10");
```

So i am blocked any ideas please ? Thanks for your help !

Here is the part of the code:

```
    public class SitesResponse {
private Result result;
private List<GeographicSite> site;
public SitesResponse () {
    this.result = new Result();
    this.site = new ArrayList<GeographicSite>();
    }
public List<GeographicSite> getSite() {
    return site;
}
public void setSite(List<GeographicSite> site) {
this.site = site;
}
```

}
Ensuite l'autre classe qui utilise SitesResponse

```
    SitesResponse response = new SitesResponse();
```

et

```
    if (testiing) {
    try {response = siteManager.geographicSitesAPIV1(args);
    response.getResult().setCode("error");
    response.getResult().setLabel("no addr found");
```

And this is what i tried ... earlier

```
    System.out.println(response.toString().getBytes().toString()+"azezae");
     //   request.Headers.Add("headername", "headervalue");
    //  request.setAttribute("X-Total-Count","10");
    //response.setAttribute("X-Result-Count", "7");
     //response.setIntHeader("mytotalcount", 5); 
     //////////////////////////////////////////////////:::::::
```

In picture where i want to add my two parameters [result from SOAPui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT5yg.png)

Comment: "it's not working" What is happening? Do you get an error?

Comment: well it doesnt work, i get a red line !! either it's delete, rename, or create a methode setAttribute  !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello again Thank you for your time, 
i was trying to edited the wrong class so what i did you just

```
    resp.addIntHeader(att, 10);
    resp.addIntHeader(att2, 5);
```

Thank you for your time and answers!